# Presto default date is not appearing correctly

Tags: sql, presto

presto> select date '0001-01-01';

Expected result: '0001-01-01'

Actual result: '0001-01-02'

Day is increasing by one not sure why.

Can anyone help me on this that how can i resolve this?

If i run the above query on presto-cli then result comes as '0001-01-01' which is expected but when i run same query via SQL workbench then result comes as '0001-01-02' which is actual result.

Comment: Don't know the tool, but timezone difference between your client and database?

Comment: No. If i execute select date '2001-01-01';  then it returns as 2001-01-01 that is what i want. but in case i give year as 0001 then problem comes.

Comment: If i ran select date '0001-01-01';  on other databases then result comes as '0001-01-01' that is what i want. Is this from presto end or SQL workbench? Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

This is because Presto uses internally Joda Time and Java Time for server APIs and JDBC uses (per JDBC standard) `java.sql.Date` and related classes.

Both Joda Time and Java Time use proleptic Gregorian calendar. This means they count days as if Gregorian calendar existed since ever.

`java.sql.Date` (and `java.util.Calendar` for that matter) uses Julian-Gregorian calendar, which may seem to be more accurate. It accounts for the fact that Julian calendar was used until some day and then Gregorian calendar was and still is used. (Of course, it's not and cannot be accurate, because the cut over date varies from country to country and spans several centuries).

My recommendation is: use `varchar` for representing historical dates and date times.

Comment: Nice answer! I was just going to say "gosh that's a long time ago!"

Comment: So you mean by running the same query via presto-cli then there is no JDBC involve in it that's why presto-cli giving expected result. right?

Comment: @sam007jat i proposed a fix for that: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/4005

Comment: Thanks @PiotrFindeisen. Can we get the latest jar which has this new fix?